# Cutting proportionally

Tags: geometry

Given any convex quadrilateral $ABCD$ and an inner point $z$ is it possible to draw/construct a line $EF$ passing through $z$ s.t. $$\frac{AE}{EB}=\frac{DF}{FC}$$

[image: quadrilateral]

Comment: I suspect it is. A proof wouldn't be too difficult, only involving continuity.

Comment: I think so too... but didn't succeed in proving it so far :)

Comment: Could you have two cases?  One in which AD and BC are not parallel, in which case you extend them until they intercept.  At that point of intercepting, draw a ray through z.  Would that create the correct E and F?  Similar triangles?

Comment: I doubt it... to have similar triangles we need $AB$ and $DC$ to be parallel.

Comment: oh yeah.  good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT1:
If we only want to prove if $ EF$ exist,that $z$ is on $EF$, it is easy.

let $A(0,0),D(x_1,0),C(x_2,y_2),B(x_3,y_3),Z(a,b),H(p,q),H$ is on $AC$with $FH//AD \to EH//BC$, if we can find $H(p,q)$, then we can draw $EF$ and the problem is solved.

with the conditions, we have:

$((x_2-x_1)y_3-x_3y_2)p^2+((x_1-a)x_2y_3+ax_2y_2+bx_2x_3-bx_2^2+bx_1x_2)p-bx_1x_2^2=0 \\ q=\dfrac{y_2p}{x_2}$

which means $H$ is constructible even by compass and straight $\implies EF$ is constructable also.

The $p$ has two solutions because we didn't limit $E,F$ 's position and another solution is for $E,F$ out of segments$AB ,CD$   but on lines  $AB ,CD$

Comment: @user149901,I didn't explain clearly and had edit it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why does the quadratic equation always have a solution? Can we prove that the discriminant is always $\ge 0$?

Comment: Yes, for sure. But it looks ugly and I will try to find a nice method to show it.

Comment: Would be very nice... because I stuck on that part.

Comment: $\Delta=(x_1y_3-bx_3+bx_2-bx_1)^2+a^2(y_3-y_2)^2-2(y_3-y_2)(ax_1y_3-2bx_1x_3+abx_3-abx_2+abx_1)>0 \iff |a(x_1y_3-bx_3+bx_2-bx_1)(y_3-y_2)|> (y_3-y_2)(ax_1y_3-2bx_1x_3+abx_3-abx_2+abx_1)$

Comment: So it seems that even when $ABCD$ is not convex such a line always exists. Only this time it does not necessarily completely lies in $ABCD$, right?

Answer (score 2):

The following might work:

Prove this for a square (trivial) Then use the result that any convex non-degenerate quadrilateral can be obtained by a perspectival (projective) transform from the square and that the ratios will be preserved.

Comment: Actually I came to this problem when trying to prove that that projective map is surjective :) How to prove that $z$ has a pre-image in $[0,1]^2$? Please have a look to [Surjectivity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1076146/surjective-bilinear-map)

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think it is always possible.

[image]

Let the red line (through Z) be that required line. It cuts AB and DC at E and F respectively.

Through E draw EG // AD cutting DC at G. It also cuts BD at E’

According to the requirement,

$\frac {DF}{FC} = \frac {AE}{EB} = \frac {DE’}{E’B}$ … [intercept theorem]

Through B, draw BX // E’F cutting DC produced at X.

BY similar triangles, $\frac {DE’}{E’B} = \frac {DF}{FC + CX}$

In other words, FC is too short for the equality to hold unless C is actually X.

Comment: $\frac {DF}{FC} = \frac {DE’}{E’B} \implies E'F//BC$

Comment: @chenbai Don’t quite understand your comment. I try to explain my over-simplified description (sorry) first. According to the requirement, we must have $\frac { DF } { FC } = \frac {AE}{EB}$. On the other hand, by intercept theorem, we found $\frac {AE}{EB} = \frac {DE’}{E’B}$. Thus, if the red line works, we must have $\frac {DF}{FC} = \frac {DE’}{E’B}$. For the last statement to be true, according to the construction made, C must be extended to X.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't think this proves that proportionally cutting line doesn't always exist. This simply proves that X and C should coincide. If you change the draw of EF by moving E up a liitle bit and F down we get the right pcture: E′F//BC and there is no contradiction anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Start with $E=A$ and $F=D$, so that $AE/EB=FD/FC$ because both are equal to $0$, and then move $E$ and $F$ toward $B$ and $C$ respectively, preserving the equality of the ratios (which go to infinity as $E\to B$ and $F\to C$).  By continuity, the line $EF$ sweeps out the entire convex quadrilateral, hence at some point passes through the point $z$.